# Prevent browser autofilling hidden fields

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, browser

We use jQuery to hide fields that aren't relevant, depending on previous answers. It seems somehow the browser (Chrome) has managed to insert the users's email address into it.  Autocomplete is already set to off.  The field id and name are like "field-32", not even anything like "username" or "email".

Is this something out of our control? I suppose could try clearing all hidden fields on submit.... but that would break other stuff where I do need hidden fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not only to hide the fields, but also to set them as disabled (`.attr("disabled", true)`). This way they won't be submitted together with the rest of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the autocomplete:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" autocomplete="new-mail">
```